# PyInstaller Isn't Bundling Accessory Script

Tags: python, import, path, pyinstaller, executable

I am attempting to make a .exe file of my Python script `main_program.py`. This script runs in a virtual environment. When I make my `main_program.exe`, I do so with my `venv` activated. My folder structure is as follows:

```
-Include
-Lib
-Scripts
-main_program.py
-accessory_script.py
```

`accessory_script.py` contains functions which I import in `main_program.py`. However, even though PyInstaller makes a mostly-functioning `main_program.exe` file, when I run the aformentioned executable, I get an `[Errno 2]: No such file or directory: path\\to\\appdata\\local\\temp\\MEI9882\\accessory_script.pyc`.

When I run `pyinstaller main_program.py` to generate the `dist` folder alone, I don't see the `accessory_script.pyc` in the folder. My question is, what do I need to do to ensure that `accessory_script.py` is incorporated into the executable of my main program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the accessory script was being incorporated into my EXE correctly by Python. Most of the functions in the accessory script were being called correctly by my main program. However, one of the functions (the one that caused the FileNotFound error) had a @reloading decorator from the `reloading` module. [This module](https://pypi.org/project/reloading/) reads the source code of a program without losing the state of the program. Because I was running my code via an EXE, there was no source code to search for. As soon as I removed this import and the associated decorators, my program worked again.